# Why javaScript's Optional Chaining Syntax does not work with Nullish Coalescing Operator when there is no method's return value?

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining, ecmascript-2020, nullish-coalescing

I"m trying the new JavaScript Optional Chaining syntax and it seems that it has an issue with methods which has no return value.
For example:

I have a restaurant object with order method in it:

```
const restaurant = {
order(i, k) {
    console.log(`I was here with ${i} and ${k}`);
   // does not return value
  }
};
```

Now if i try to check if the order method exist inside restaurant object like below, it returns 'undefiend':

```
const orderCheck = restaurant.order?.(0, 1);
console.log(orderCheck ); // it returns undefined
```

Now the problem is, if i use above case with Nullish Coalescing Operator like below, it does not work:

```
console.log(restaurant.order?.(0, 1) ?? 'Method does not exist');

Output: 
I was here with 0 and 1
Method does not exist
```

ISSUE:
Now the issue in above statement is, the optional chaining syntax even finds the order method & prints "I was here with 0 and 1" but still returns 'undefiend' which makes Nullish Coalescing Operator to proceed and even it prints 'Method does not exist' too as default value?

Now, if i allow the order method to return a value then it works fine with Nullish Coalescing Operator and it does not proceed.

```
 const restaurant = {
    order(i, k) {
        console.log(`I was here with ${i} and ${k}`);
        return '1';
      }
    };
```

If check again:

```
console.log(restaurant.order?.(0, 1) ?? 'Method does not exist');

Output: 
I was here with 0 and 1
```

Is it necessary for optional chaining syntax to expect a return value other than nullish values from a method in order to check its availability?

In above case, the order method does exist then How to prevent Nullish Coalescing Operator to not to proceed for the default 'Method does not exist'?

I'm testing it with modern browsers (Chrome & firfox) and i have also enabled the javaScript experimental features in Chrome but it still work the same above way.

Any thoughts would be helpful? Thanks

Comment: _"if i try to check if the order method exist inside restaurant object like below, it returns 'undefiend"_ - what do you expect it to return? Method exists in the object, so it is called; method doesn't explicitly returns anything, as a result, you get `undefined`.

Comment: @Yousaf, yes that's right, method returns undefined which makes the Nullish Coalescing Operator proceed for default value even the method does exist. It should not proceed for "'Method does not exist'"? In my case, it also say ''Method does not exist''?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is.`console.log(restaurant?.order(0, 1) ?? 'Method does not exist');`

Comment: @Irfan _" It should not proceed for "'Method does not exist'"?"_ - it should because nullish coalescing operator returns the right-hand side operand if the left operand is null or undefined. In your case, left operand is undefined.

Comment: @Yousaf, that's correct, i agree. Then How to prevent Nullish Coalescing Operator to not proceed for the default 'Method does not exist' Even the method exist? any solution in that particular case? Since we don't know if an API returns or not?

Comment: I would just use simple `if` statement to check if the method exists or not.

Answer (score 4):

This is not related to optional chaining.

> The [`Nullish Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator) returns its right-hand side operand when its left-hand side operand is null or undefined, and otherwise returns its left-hand side operand.

Therefore, the optional chaining is already working as the function exists but its return value is `undefined`, hence the operator goes to the right part.

Note:

- the log inside the function is showing as it's getting executed first but no value is being returned.
- if function didn't exist, in this case it will also compute to `undefined` due to the [`optional chaining`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) so the right side of the `nullish operator` would be taken as well

```js
let obj = {};
console.log("function doesn't exist", obj?.foo?.(), obj?.foo?.() ?? 'right');

obj = { foo: () => {} };
console.log("function exists but doesn't return", obj?.foo?.(), obj?.foo?.() ?? 'right');

obj = { foo: () => { return 'left'; } };
console.log("function exists and returns", obj?.foo?.(), obj?.foo?.() ?? 'right');
```

Edit: to prevent Nullish Coalescing Operator to not proceed for the default 'Method does not exist' Even the method exist

```js
obj = { foo: () => {} };
console.log(obj?.foo && typeof obj.foo === 'function' ? obj.foo() : 'right');
```

Comment: So to make the Optional chaining to work with Nullish coalescing properly, the method should always return a value?

Comment: This is the role of the nullish operator, it will take the left side if the function returns a value. The optional chaining is used to make sure the function exists before calling it.

Comment: Then How to prevent Nullish Coalescing Operator to not proceed for the default 'Method does not exist' Even the method exist?

Comment: I edited the answer, I think this is the case you're pointing to, in case the function exists, whatever the return value is, take it instead of the default value

Comment: So you mean, in that particular case, the Nullish Coalescing Operator would NOT work? and we have to go back to logical operators & conditional operator?

Comment: Yes I think so, the nullish operator doesn't include a condition, it just falls back to the right part if the left (the return value in this case) is null or undefined. This is why the condition should first check for the existence of the function and then call it if it exists, otherwise falls back to the right part as well.

Comment: Please accept the answer as the solution if it solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

With `restaurant.order?.(0, 1)` you check if the method exists, and if it does, then call it and return the result of the call. In your case, `order(0, 1)` returns undefined, therefore `restaurant.order?(0, 1)` also returns undefined.